# Qt signals and slots for multiple objects

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I'm having little problem here. I'm having troubles with signals & slots. I'll try to explain with pseudocode. So, here it goes.

I have main thread (mainwindow.cpp) where I'm creating new objects when new client connects.

mainwindow.h:

```
signals:
   void changeText();
...
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
connect(tcpserver, SIGNAL(changeText()), this, SIGNAL(changeText()));

...

MyClass *m = new MyClass(this);
connect(this, SIGNAL(changeText()), m, SLOT(changeText()));
```

I have also tcpserver class, which creates new QThread when client connects and connects both signals.

tcpserver.h:

```
signals:
    void changeText();
protected:
    void incomingConnection(int handle);
```

tcpserver.cpp:

```
void incomingConnection(int handle)
{
    QTcpSocket *s = new QTcpSocket(this);
    s->setSocketDescriptor(handle);
    mythread *thread = new mythread(s, this);
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(changeText()), this, SIGNAL(changeText()));
}
```

The problem is following:
I have 3 objects, main thread, tcpserver class which inherits from QTcpServer, and the mythread class which inherits from QThread class.

When I'm creating new "mythread"-s from "tcpserver" and connecting signals, all signals from new threads are connected to "tcpserver"-s signals, so, e.g if 10 clients do something, all signals are sent to "tcpserver" which makes problem for me. I want to understand which signal should I connect to MyClass via QTread -> TcpServer -> MainWindow.

Sorry for my English, if you don't understand what I mean, I'll try to explain better.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "makes problem for me" are you trying to differentiate the incoming connections? If so you can use the int socketDescriptor as a signal argument to differentiate the calls in the MyClass slot

Comment: I'm bit confused here, because I'm new to Qt. If I pass socketDescriptor in signal, it will still cause a lot of signals to be emitted instead of one-by-one. Can you show me little example of it please?

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand your problem. I do not mind showing you an example provided I understand what you are trying to do. Can you update your question and state what your expected output should be and what your currently getting.

Comment: You have not stated what you want or why the current situation is a problem for you. Without either information there is no way to help.

Comment: I'm sorry, code is really big but I can show you graph of flow how it should work. http://s21.postimage.org/yfm1ufudz/Signal_Slot.png If you take a look here, I want to QThread_1's signal to be connected to Object_1, QThread_2's to Object_2 and so on..

Comment: typo? "connect(tcpserver, SIGNAL(changeText()), this, SIGNAL(changeText()));" should it be SLOT?

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

- in your "incomingConnection(int)", i doubt any memory leak for the objects created in heap (tcpsocket, and mythread), use QList (or other container) in your tcpserver to hold the sockets created in your "incomingConnection(int)"
- prefix the name of SLOT(changeText) with your classes to clarify which objects is your intented sender/receiver
- I dont think you cant connect two signal like

  connect(thread, SIGNAL(changeText()), this, SIGNAL(changeText()));

Comment: > I dont think you cant connect two signal like
You can. Read documentation :-)

P.S I'm already saving list of tcp sockets and I'll use QMap for saving threads too. Thanks.

Comment: No problem :-) It's very useful sometimes.